# Sharepoint - I want to use javascript OpenPopUpPage to popup a div already on the page

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I am using a content editor webpart to execute some javascript on a sharepoint page. I just need a quick modal popup to display some text so I am attempting to use the OpenPopUpPage function. It seems as though the OpenPopUpPage script can only be used to render a link from another page. Is there any way I can use the OpenPopUpPage to render a div located on the current page?

Thank You.

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenPopUpPage only opens a modal which is basically an iframe which the source is another page, usually an Application Page that lives in _layouts.

You can easily create that page with visual studio and deploy it as a feature.

if you want to stay away from visual studio you can use jquery that has multiple modal plugins that will suit your requirements. To include jquery you have several options like modifying the page using sharepoint designer or even include it in your master page.

Answer (score 1):

As Luis said, you cannot use OpenPopUpPage without putting your content into a document you can link to.

But you can use SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog which can accept an html document object instead of a link. That just means you need to create the DOM on the fly with your content. But no reason why you cannot have a function that accepts your content as a string and wraps it into a DOM before passing to SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog. There is a simple example [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5abbf121-21f5-497a-88b7-a0288d89c388/spuimodaldialog-without-url).